# Proof of derivative of $\log(|x|)$ definition of derivatives

Tags: limits, derivatives

How can we prove $$\frac{d(\log(|x|))}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$$ for $x\neq0$?
I tried proving and for $x > 0$, I proved it to be $$\frac{1}{x};$$ but for $x < 0$, I am getting it  $$\frac{-1}{x}.$$

Can anyone please prove it?

Comment: You need to show us how you’re getting $-1/x$ for $x<0$

Comment: It is $$\frac{d}{dx}\log (|x|)=\frac{1}{|x|}\frac{d}{dx}(|x|)$$ and $\dfrac{d}{dx}(|x|)=\dfrac{|x|}{x}$.

Comment: $\text{MathJax}$ Tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok see first let's take $f(x)=log|x|$

Case:$$x<0$$
For this, $log|x|=log(-x)$
Now $$f'(x)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{log(-(x+h)) - log(-x)}{h}$$

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{log\frac{-(x+h)}{(-x)}}{h}$$

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{x})(log(1+(\frac{h}{x}))^{\frac{x}{h}}$$
After solving, as $$e=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}$$
Putting $\frac{h}{x}=t$

You will get-
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
But again as assumed here $x<0$ this will also be negative or slope will be negative.
I think for positive x you can do it easily.

Comment: I think that should be 1 - (h/x)?

Comment: No see you replace x with (x+h) so that minus sign is is with x but we are replacing x not -x that minus belongs to the function condition but in limit I think you write instead of x with (x+h)

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See $$\log|x|=
\begin{cases}
 \log(-x)&\text{if}\, x<0\\
 \log x&\text{if}\,x>0\\
\end{cases}$$
Now $$\frac{d(\log|x|)}{dx}=\begin{cases}
 \dfrac{1}{-x}(-1)&\text{if}\, x<0\\
 \dfrac{1}{x}&\text{if}\,x>0\\
\end{cases}$$
Now actually the answer considering just magnitude is same but still $$x>0, \frac{1}{x}$$ is positive or the slope is positive. For $$x<0, \frac{1}{x}$$ is negative as $x<0$ so slope is negative. You can confirm this by graph of $\log|x|$. So answer is $$\frac{1}{x}$$ anyway.

[image]

As you can see from graph negative slope for negative x and positive for positive $x$.

Comment: Can you please prove it using limits?